# Regular expression on wordpress navigation

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am really really bad at regular expression, I don't know why but I can never really figure it out.

at the moment I use the following code to put an image in front of my first navigation item:

```
$nav_out = preg_replace('/<a([^>]*)>/', '<a$1><img src="http://myimage.gif" border="0" />', wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'  => 'menu-1', 'echo' => 0, 'container'       => false )),1);
echo $nav_out;
```

However I need the image to be at the BACK of my first item. I tried a bunch of things but I just can't get it to work :(

Can anybody help me out here?

Would be really really gratefull!

EDIT: I took some screenshots

my original one with the image at the front

```
$nav_out = preg_replace('/<a([^>]*)>/', '<a$1><img src="http://www.bimiii.com/myimg.gif" border="0" />',
```

[image: sqfqsd]

the suggestion made by marcio

```
$nav_out = preg_replace('/<a([^>]*)>/', '<img src="http://www.bimiii.com/myimg.gif" border="0" /><a$1>',
```

[image: qsdfsd]

and I know this one is wrong but I just wanted to show it anyway

```
$nav_out = preg_replace('</a>', '</a><img src="http://www.bimiii.com/myimg.gif" border="0" />',
```

[image: qsdfqsdfs]

Comment: you mean to position the image before the link tag?

Comment: no, it says "back". But it's in front now, the front one works, I just can't get it to the back

Comment: Ok, so I see this is not a regex problem. It's a CSS + HTML problem and you will need to provide more information. How about show a small screen shot of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex in this case is used to match any anchor tag and inject the image near the anchors in your menu. You can reposition the image just using CSS:

```
#your-menu-container-selector ul li img {
  float:right;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dude, it worked!! I also changed the margins to get it at the same position, but now it worked ;)

Thanks a bunch!! I owe u

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you meant this?

```
$nav_out = preg_replace('/<a([^>]*)>/', '<img src="http://myimage.gif" border="0" /><a$1>', wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location'  => 'menu-1', 'echo' => 0, 'container'       => false )),1);
```

Comment: This is not really working, now the image is just floating above the link :o

Comment: look at my comment on your answer